# Создание прямоугольника с закруглёнными углами с текстом при нажатии пробела

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь реализовать поиск по словам. При вводе слова и нажатии пробела, вокруг слова должен образоваться прямоугольник с скруглёнными углами, и далее вводится второе слово для поиска и так по кругу.

Пытался реализовать через добавление обычного Rectangle и вставки по верх него блока с текстом, но после этого перестает быть активным TextBox.

Вот моя попытка

```
Rectangle rec_test = new Rectangle();
rec_test.Width = (i * 10);
rec_test.Height = 20;
rec_test.RadiusX = 10;
rec_test.RadiusY = 10;
rec_test.Fill = Brushes.Orange;
rec_test.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
GridSearch.Children.Add(rec_test);
GridSearch.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Text = text });
```

Просьба помочь или посоветовать что-нибудь.

Comment: Научитесь делать привязки. Далее сделайте класс, который будет содержать текст и bool свойство выделения. В XAML сделайте border, внутри которого будет текст, ну и по триггеру меняйте стиль border'a, задав нужный `BorderThickness` и `CornerRadius`.

Comment: Не понял насчёт класса, что за bool свойство выделения?

Comment: Ну флаг который указывает, выделен элемент или нет. Как я понял

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну смотрите, простой пример:

- Создадим для начала основной класс, я назову его `MainViewModel`.
- Зададим `DataContext` текущему окну. Вам пока понять принцип, по этому прям в конструкторе окна, в `MainWindow.xaml.cs`, после `InitializeComponent();` пишем `DataContext = new MainViewModel();`.
- Дальше создадим класс, который будет отвечать за одно слово, назовем его `WordViewModel`.
- В этом классе нам нужно создать два публичных свойства, одно будет содержать само слово, а другое, "статус" выделения у данного слова, ну и что бы было удобно с ним работать, будет через конструктор задавать нужные нам значения.

  ```
  class WordViewModel 
  {
      public WordViewModel(string text, bool isSelected = false)
      {
          Text = text;
          IsSelected = isSelected;
      }

      public string Text { get; set; }
      public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Тут свойство `IsSelected` предполагает, что оно будет изменено во время выполнения, через код. Следовательно нам нужно реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` (о нем я думаю вы прочитаете отдельно), наш класс будет выглядеть теперь так:

  ```
  class WordViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
      public WordViewModel(string text, bool isSelected = false)
      {
          Text = text;
          IsSelected = isSelected;
      }

      public string Text { get; set; }

      private bool isSelected;
      public bool IsSelected
      {
          get => isSelected;
          set
          {
              isSelected = value;
              OnPropertyChanged();
          }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
      protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
      {
          PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
  }
  ```
- Теперь я в `MainViewModel` добавлю метод, который будет генерировать мне коллекцию из предоставленного текста:

  ```
  private IEnumerable<WordViewModel> Generate()
  {
      var words = "мышка стена сачок витраж губка тумбочка куколка бар ветеринар метель огурец лапоть краска соска коридор снежинка обложка фитиль завтрак ключ ведро комета пружина киоск воробей двигатель персик флаг дрожжи кондуктор";
      return words.Split().Select(x => new WordViewModel(x));
  }
  ```
- Имея это мы можем сделать коллекцию всех наших слов и добавить в нее нужные данные:

  ```
  public ObservableCollection<WordViewModel> Words { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
      Words = new ObservableCollection<WordViewModel>(Generate());
  }
  ```
- Теперь сделаем поиск, тут тоже все просто. Нам нужно свойство, в `set` которого мы будет вызывать определенный метод. Сам метод просто пройдется по коллекции слов и если слово было вписано - заменит ему `IsSelected`:

  ```
  private string searchText;
  public string SearchText
  {
      get => searchText;
      set
      {
          searchText = value;
          Search(value.Split());
      }
  }

  public void Search(string[] words)
  {
      foreach (var word in Words)
          word.IsSelected = words.Contains(word.Text);
  }
  ```
- Осталось нам сделать дизайн.

  - Тут мы создаем `ItemsControl`, который привязываем к `Words`, ему зададим `WrapPanel` в `ItemsPanelTemplate` (это заполнит все пространство нашими словами)
  - И переопределим стиль каждого элемента - стиль простой, `border` с заданными параметрами обводки и закруглением углов, внутри простой `TextBlock`. Также в стиле сделаем триггер, который будет проверять наш `IsSelected` и если он `true`, то мы меняем цвет нашего `border`'a.
  - Также сделаем отдельно простой `TextBox`, который будет привязан к `SelectedText` и зададим еще `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, что бы поиск был моментальным (не при потере фокуса элемента).

В итоге получаем что то вроде этого:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Words}" Margin="30">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" Margin="2">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Padding="5"/>
                </Border>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             TextAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" Width="300"
             Text="{Binding SearchText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

Все, вот у нас и готовое приложение, запускаем и проверяем:

[image: result]

Как видим, все введенные нами слова успешно "обводятся в прямоугольник с закругленными углами". Так что удачи в изучении WPF!