# combobox поиск как в поисковике

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, autocomplete

У меня имеется ComboBox с немалым кол-вом строк. `isEditable = true`. Есть необходимость во время ввода, показывать строки, которые начинаются на введенное значение.

Пример:

Начинаем вводить -

`Алма`

Подсказка ComboBox из выпадающего списка:

`Алмаз`

`Алмазный бур`

`Алмазный блок`

Были попытки через [этот](https://gist.github.com/mariodivece/0bbade976aea8d416d52) код, но поле ввода жутко висло, вариант провалился. Не знаю как быть.

Comment: Я однажды делал [такой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/987581/220553), думаю на его основе можно реализовать то, что вы хотите.

Comment: [Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001842/dynamic-filter-of-wpf-combobox-based-on-text-input) что нашел

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да, спасибо, на основе вашего примера создал похожий метод для меня. Можете запостить как ответ, отмечу как решение!

Answer (score 0):

[Вот метод](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979695/how-to-make-that-wpf-combobox-keyboard-text-search-will-works-correctly-if-isedi), который я использовал в своём проекте.

Это уже встроеная в WPF функция, просто при декларации ComboBox'а в XAML надо прописать так же это:
`IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"` .

Так же возможно вам пригодится эта строка, которую тоже можно добавить в декларацию ComboBox'а - `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`